# Python Regex return words containing double character

Tags: python, regex

I have a big string "a" and I want to extract all words with double characters from there. I need words as output (not lines or characters).
I tried simple things like this:

```
re.findall(r'\b.*([A-Za-z])\1.*\b', a)
```

which gives a list of letters.

I also tried this:

```
pat='(\w*)\1'
def f(a, pat):
   pat = r'(\w*%s\w*)' % pat
   return re.findall(pat, a)
print (f(a,pat))
```

It gave me empty list. So I have two problems: 1) How to return words? 2) What regex to use to select words with double letters (like 'look', 'settle' etc).

Comment: Your first attempt is good, but put parentheses around the word: `\b(.*([a-zA-Z])\1.*)\b`

Comment: Then it gives me an `error: cannot refer to an open group at position 15"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
import re

def f(a):
   return [x[0] for x in re.findall(r'\b([a-z]*([a-z]+)\2[a-z]*)\b', a, re.IGNORECASE)]

print(f("We Choose To Go To The Moon"))
```

Which will output:

```py
['Choose', 'Moon']
```

This works when there's multiple repeated letters (`success`) or when the repeated letters are different cases (`Eel`). Returns an empty array if there are no words with repeating letters.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this:**

```py
import re


def find_words(text):
    words = re.findall(r'(\w*(\w)\2\w*)', text, re.IGNORECASE)
    return words

text = 'look book cat battle settle america google facebook gmail ball'
words = find_words(text=text)

for word, char in words:
    print(f'Word: {word} - Double Char: {char}')
```

**Output:**

```sh
Word: look - Double Char: o
Word: book - Double Char: o
Word: battle - Double Char: t
Word: settle - Double Char: t
Word: google - Double Char: o
Word: facebook - Double Char: o
Word: ball - Double Char: l
```

Comment: I think raw string like `r'(\w*(\w)\2\w*)'` is still preferred even it's fine for now.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. now i think it will be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

1). The pattern you tried `\b.*([A-Za-z])\1.*\b` will:

- match the first word boundary
- then match 2 of the same chars from ranges a-z A-Z in the string
- then match the last word boundary because `.*` can match any character so the whole match is not limited to a "word"

Then using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will only return the capture group value, which is a single character.

2). In the pattern `(\w*)\1` the quantifier for the word characters is 0 or more. It will for example match all positions as an empty string will also match, and could possible also match 2 times abc like `abcabc`

---

You can use a single capture group, and to get all the matches use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead.

```
\w*([a-zA-Z])\1\w*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w*` Match optional word characters
- `([a-zA-Z])\1` Match a single char from ranges a-z A-Z, followed by matching the exact same char using a backreference `\1`
- `\w*` Match optional word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sIOJUn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dk7yBo)

```
import re

pattern = r"\w*([a-zA-Z])\1\w*"
s = 'settle, look, test'
for m in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
settle
look
```